# How to map numpy arrays to one another?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy

I have two (A, B) boolean arrays of the same finite, but arbitrarily large, and only known at runtime shape and dimensions.

I want to calculate the value of a boolean function of corresponding elements in A and B and store them in C. At last I need a list of tuples where C is true.

How to get there?

I dont want to iterate over the single elements, because I dont know how many dimensions there are, there must be a better way.

```
>>> A = array([True, False, True, False, True, False]).reshape(2,3)
>>> B = array([True, True, False, True, True, False]).reshape(2,3)
>>> A == B
array([[ True, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

as wanted, but:

```
>>> A and B
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

How do I get "A and B"?

I tried "map", "zip", "nditer" and searched for other methods unsuccessfully.

As for the things with the tuples, I need something like "argmax" for booleans, but didn't find anything either.

Do you know somethign, that might help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the & operator:

```
In [5]: A & B

array([[ True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

The big win with the logical_and call is that you can use the out parameter:

```
In [6]: C = empty_like(A)

In [7]: logical_and(A, B, C)

array([[ True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a function in NumPy:

```
numpy.logical_and(A,B)
```